# Converting C Program Code to Javascript, producing different Result?

Tags: javascript, c

I'm converting a pretty simple program I made in C code into Javascript. The code are identical, however I changed the code into Javascript syntax. For some reason my simple calculation in javascript language is giving me a different result than the one in C. Take a look below. I did some test to see if some of the variables values were the same. Everything, S, S1, S2, V1, V2, T4, LCP are the same. BUT T2 has a different value.

```
S = lesserofcalc(S1,S2);
alert("S1--->" + S1);
alert("S2--->" + S2);
alert("S--->" + S);
//printf("S1:%.2lf | S2:%.2lf | S:%.2lf | T4:%.2lf | V1:%.2lf | K2P:%.2lf \n",S1,S2,S,T4,V1, K2P);
if (LCPK<=LCPRATE*YY){
    LCP = LCPK;
} else {
    LCP = LCPRATE*YY;
}

V2 = OHP();
V2 = roundFIX(V2);
alert("V1--->" + V1);
alert("V2--->" + V2);
alert("T4--->" + T4);
alert("LCP--->" + LCP);

T2 = T4+V1+V2-S-LCP; *GIVING DIFFERENT VALUE FROM C ????*
alert("T2--->" + T2);
T2 = roundFIX(T2);
```

C Program:

```
S = lesserofcalc(S1,S2);
printf("S1-----> %.2lf \n", S1);
printf("S2-----> %.2lf \n", S2);
printf("S-----> %.2lf \n", S);

//printf("S1:%.2lf | S2:%.2lf | S:%.2lf | T4:%.2lf | V1:%.2lf | K2P:%.2lf \n",S1,S2,S,T4,V1, K2P);
if (LCPK<=LCPRATE*YY){
    LCP = LCPK;
} else {
    LCP = LCPRATE*YY;
}

V2 = OHP();
V2 = roundFIX(V2);
printf("v1-----> %.2lf \n", V1);
printf("V2-----> %.2lf \n", V2);
printf("T4-----> %.2lf \n", T4);
printf("LCP-----> %.2lf \n", LCP);
T2 = T4+V1+V2-S-LCP;
printf("T2-----> %.2lf \n", T2);

T2 = roundFIX(T2);
```

Comment: What are the types of your variables?

Comment: they're float, or double.. it doesnt make sense to me.. i should get same result, but T2 is giving me a different value!

Comment: That is some nasty looking code... Consider better named variables/functions and the problem may solve itself.

Comment: It would really help if you showed us the input and output values you are using for your calculation.

Comment: So, if the only bit that is causing problems is the `T2` calculation, then why do we need to see the other parts of your code? Show us the code with the other variables with hard-coded inputs, as you say these values are all the same.

Comment: sorry this is just a snippet of the bigger program..

Comment: well T2 is the only one that does not match.. since the other variables are used to calculate T2 I want to see what there values are.. And the weird thing is, the values of these variables are the exact same as C, BUT javascript is giving me different T2 value..

Comment: So, just show **THAT** code with **THOSE** values!

Comment: I decided to test, removing LCP from T2 = T4+V1+V2-S-LCP... so T2 = T4+V1+V2-S and got the same result as the C... i dont know what can explain this... but something is up with the values

Comment: NVM. its not LCP its S that is giving me inccorect values. I displayed the value of S twice in different areas within the function, and its different. I guess, another function is changing it, but why does it work for my C program...

Comment: thats weird, i decided to reposition the statement that gives me S in the function. And its finally working.. wtf, why doesn't C give me the same progroblem..?

Answer (score 0):

Solve. the problem.. sorry was kind of a pointless question.. exact same code in C and javascript, I guess its different how they run instructions/functions... or what not..